# Is it possible to utilize the Chrome input style for extensions?

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing Google Chrome extensions. In order to give the user a feeling of unity, I'm copying the style of the Google Chrome controls. They look like this:

[image: Google Chrome styles]

However, I would like to utilize the existing styles from Google Chrome directly instead of duplicating them into my CSS code. Is there a way to achieve this?

The resulting buttons, checkboxes, selectboxes etc. should look exactly like the ones in Google Chrome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only for a very specific case: the [new-style options page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/optionsV2) AKA optionsV2.

You can specify that you want to use Chrome styles:

```
  "options_ui": {
    "page": "options.html",
    "chrome_style": true
  },
```

Developers [specifically said](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=430054#c10) that while it would be nice to provide the style for use in every page, but it "became scary in the implementation".

---

Anecdotal evidence shows that it works for pageAction/browserAction popups. The corresponding bug:
[Support chrome_style from options_ui.chrome_style in other extension view types](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=459446) (it's not marked as complete).

Comment: So it doesn't work in the popup window of the extension icon?

Comment: Quoting kalman: _"The best we can really hope for is add annotations for this on a case-by-case basis. For example, support that chrome_style key in the browser_action and page_action manifest keys. [...] and I would gladly accept patches for that."_ So, no, not currently.

Comment: Hey Wait! This **does** work on the popup window of the extension. Please edit your answer!

Comment: Are you sure? It's not [marked as complete](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=459446).

Comment: Yes, I just tried it and it works perfectly on `select`, `input[type=text]` and `button` so far.

Comment: So you see a real difference with and without that key? Which Chrome version?

Comment: 42.0.2311.135. Of course I tested it throughfully, you can trust me. I removed my own CSS and it looks good. I removed your code and it looks bad. This measn: Your code is the solution :)

Comment: Then you should probably comment about it on the bug I linked, can you do that?